# Acurracy and loss don't changing among 50 epochs

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, data-science

I am trying to develop ALPR system, using python and keras. I generated dataset (600 000 samples) which contains from plates with format C-I-I-I-C-C (C-char,I-Int)

My model does not improve or degrade through the 50 epochs, It's just fluctuated. I do not know what's going on with weights.

Please, tell me what's going on (is it overfitting or underfitting)?
And, if it is not a problem please give some advice on how to solve that problem.

P.S. I tried to increase or decrease the number of neurons per layer, tried to use pre-trained models (such as VGG), to increase and decrease depth of network.

Some plots.
**NOTE!: The last plot is median of out1-out6 layers accuracy**

[image: Model accuracy for output "class_img", which indicate is a number on image]

[image: Total model loss]

[image: Median of accuracy the rest 6 outputs, which illustrates a character]

Here it is my code.

```
count_train=0
count_test=0

def convertation(val):
    zero = np.zeros(len(sources.DIGITS))
    zero[sources.DIGITS.index(val)] = 1
    return np.array(zero)

def data_generator(batch=32,val=False):
    if val:
        directory='K:\DATASETS\syntetic_cars\\mix_test'
    else:
        directory = 'K:\DATASETS\syntetic_cars\\no_reg'
    files=os.listdir(directory)
    i = 0
    while True:
        x=[]
        l1=[]
        l2=[]
        l3=[]
        l4=[]
        l5=[]
        l0=[]
        y2=[]
        for b in range(batch):
            if i == len(files):
                i = 0
                random.shuffle(files)
            sample = random.choice(files)
            sam=sample.split('_')[-2]
            i += 1
            try:
                image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(directory,sample))/255

            except TypeError:
                pil_image = Image.open(os.path.join(directory, sample))
                r, g, b = pil_image.split()
                img = Image.merge("RGB", (b, g, r))
                open_cv_image = np.array(img)
                image = open_cv_image[:, :, ::-1].copy()/255
            x.append(image)
            y=sam
            y2.append(int(sample.split('_')[-1][:-4]))

            l0.append(convertation(y[0]))
            l1.append(convertation(y[1]))
            l2.append(convertation(y[2]))
            l3.append(convertation(y[3]))
            l4.append(convertation(y[4]))
            l5.append(convertation(y[5]))

            yield np.array(x), \
                  {'class_img': np.array(y2),
                   'out1': np.array(l0),
                   'out2': np.array(l1),
                   'out3': np.array(l2),
                   'out4': np.array(l3),
                   'out5': np.array(l4),
                   'out6': np.array(l5)}


def train(epoch,count_train,count_test,plotting=False):
    tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', histogram_freq=0,
                              write_graph=True, write_images=True)
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="K:\Diplom\\reco_model\model.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.6f}-{loss:.6f}.hdf5",
                                 monitor='val_loss',
                                 verbose=1,
                                 save_best_only=False,
                                 mode='min')

    batch=48


    train_Gen=data_generator(batch)
    test_Gen=data_generator(batch,True)    
    input_data = Input(name='the_input', shape=(64, 128, 3), dtype='float32')

    x = Conv2D(4,
               padding='same',
               kernel_initializer='random_uniform',
               bias_initializer='zeros',
               activation='relu',
               name='conv1',
               kernel_size=(3, 3))(input_data)
    x = MaxPooling2D(name='pooling1',pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

    x = Conv2D(64,
               padding='same',
               kernel_initializer='random_uniform',
               bias_initializer='zeros',
               activation='relu',
               name='conv2',
               kernel_size=(5, 5))(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(name='pooling2',pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x =Dense(8,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='random_uniform',bias_initializer='zeros')(x)

    class_img = Dense(1,
                      name='class_img',
                      kernel_initializer='random_uniform',
                      bias_initializer='zeros',
                      activation='sigmoid')(x)
    out1 = Dense(len(sources.DIGITS),
                 kernel_initializer='random_uniform',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 name='out1',
                 activation='softmax')(x)
    out2 = Dense(len(sources.DIGITS),
                 kernel_initializer='random_uniform',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 name='out2',
                 activation='softmax')(x)
    out3 = Dense(len(sources.DIGITS),
                 kernel_initializer='random_uniform',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 name='out3',
                 activation='softmax')(x)
    out4 = Dense(len(sources.DIGITS),
                 kernel_initializer='random_uniform',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 name='out4',
                 activation='softmax')(x)
    out5 = Dense(len(sources.DIGITS),
                 kernel_initializer='random_uniform',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 name='out5',
                 activation='softmax')(x)
    out6 = Dense(len(sources.DIGITS),
                 kernel_initializer='random_uniform',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 name='out6',
                 activation='softmax')(x)


    model= Model(inputs=input_data,
                 outputs=[class_img,
                          out1,
                          out2,
                          out3,
                          out4,
                          out5,
                          out6])

    model.summary()

    losses = {
        "class_img": "binary_crossentropy",
        "out1": "categorical_crossentropy",
        "out2": "categorical_crossentropy",
        "out3": "categorical_crossentropy",
        "out4": "categorical_crossentropy",
        "out5": "categorical_crossentropy",
        "out6": "categorical_crossentropy"}   

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=losses,
                  # loss_weights=lossWeights,
                  metrics=["accuracy"]
                  )


    print('Count of train steps:',int(count_train/batch))
    print('Count of test steps:',int(count_test/batch),end='\n\n')
    history = model.fit_generator(train_Gen,
        steps_per_epoch=int(count_train/batch),
        validation_data=test_Gen,
        validation_steps=int(count_test/batch),
        initial_epoch=0,
        verbose=1,
        callbacks=[checkpoint,tensorboard],
        epochs=epoch)


    if plotting:
        val_res=[]
        for ep in range(0,len(history.history['val_out1_acc'])):
            acc = []
            acc.append(history.history['val_out1_acc'][ep])
            acc.append(history.history['val_out2_acc'][ep])
            acc.append(history.history['val_out3_acc'][ep])
            acc.append(history.history['val_out4_acc'][ep])
            acc.append(history.history['val_out5_acc'][ep])
            acc.append(history.history['val_out6_acc'][ep])
            val_res.append(statistics.median(acc))
        acc_res=[]

        for ep in range(0,len(history.history['val_out1_acc'])):
            acc = []
            acc.append(history.history['out1_acc'][ep])
            acc.append(history.history['out2_acc'][ep])
            acc.append(history.history['out3_acc'][ep])
            acc.append(history.history['out4_acc'][ep])
            acc.append(history.history['out5_acc'][ep])
            acc.append(history.history['out6_acc'][ep])
            acc_res.append(statistics.median(acc))

        plt.plot(acc_res)
        plt.plot(val_res)
        plt.title('Model accuracy (chars)')
        plt.ylabel('accuracy')
        plt.xlabel('epoch')
        plt.legend(['train','test'], loc='upper left')
        plt.show()

        plt.plot(history.history['class_img_loss'])
        plt.plot(history.history['val_class_img_loss'])
        plt.title('Model accuracy (plate)')
        plt.ylabel('accuracy')
        plt.xlabel('epoch')
        plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
        plt.show()

        plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
        plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
        plt.title('Model loss')
        plt.ylabel('loss')
        plt.xlabel('epoch')
        plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
        plt.show()

directory='K:\DATASETS\syntetic_cars\\no_reg'
count_train=len(os.listdir(directory))
directory = 'K:\DATASETS\syntetic_cars\\mix_test'
count_test=len(os.listdir(directory))
train(50,count_train,count_test,True)
```

Comment: It's the same picture for both links, didn't you mean to post a different set of pictures?

Comment: @miselking thank you, I am sorry for this misclick :)

Comment: can you show some of the code you've already tried?

Comment: @nickthefreak You meant architecture that I tried?

Comment: ultimately yes, but I meant actual code snippets. it is near impossible to tell if the loss not decreasing is an issue with network structure or a bug at the moment, so adding all relevant information will certainly help understanding

Comment: @nickthefreak I added my code and changed a bit description of my problem, doesit enough?

Comment: could it be that in the first `Conv2D`, collapsing to 4 is a bit too aggressive?

Comment: @KaiAeberli To be honest, I tried many architectures with 48,64 and so on units per layer, and had the same result generally

Comment: ok - i feel it may be an underfitting problem, as your training accuracy doesn't decrease so it's not learning anything: you might need more complexity in the model - more layers.

Comment: @KaiAeberli First of all I tried https://matthewearl.github.io/2016/05/06/cnn-anpr/ architecture, it was the same

Comment: @NikitaBelov Interesting - when running that architecture, did you run it on the data mentioned here: https://github.com/matthewearl/deep-anpr/ , or on your own data?

Comment: @KaiAeberli I generated data with same code, but have changed font and structure of plate, I mean number format. So, I really don't understand what's going one. I already tried to use VGG instead of this convolution layers, no sense.

Comment: @NikitaBelov it may help to first replicate exactly what was done there, with the same font, number of characters in number plate etc and check if you can match. Then slowly change one constraint at a time and see when the accuracy starts stalling.

Comment: @KaiAeberli Oh, I found one mistake in my code, maybe It was because I add one space to `yield`

Comment: Hi Nikita Belov, Can you please let us know if your issue is resolved now, after removing the space, you mentioned in the above command? Else, we can try for the resolution. Thanks.

Comment: @TensorflowSupport Yeah, the issue have already solved, actually it was my fold while generating batches

Comment: @NikitaBelov,
Can you please share the Corrected/Working Code in the answer (only if possible for you) so that it would help the people/community facing similar issue. Thanks!

Comment: Have you normalized your data ?